# как выдать роль человеку через слеш команду nextcord

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import nextcord
from nextcord import Interaction
from nextcord.ext import commands

id_server = 000000000000000000
opov = 000000000000000000
role_id = 000000000000000000

@bot.slash_command(name="wl", description="role", guild_ids=[id_server])
async def wl(interaction: Interaction, 
             name: nextcord.Member = nextcord.SlashOption(
              name='имя', description='имя пользователя')):
    await interaction.response.send_message("lol")

    pov = nextcord.Member
    guild = self.get_guild(id_server) #ошибка self
    role = guild.get_role(role_id)
    await pov.add_roles(role)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

бот не выдаёт роль выбранному человеку

Comment: Что такое `self` в вашем коде? Нигде не видел, чтобы `self` было объявлено как какая-то переменная. Обычно `self` используется, чтобы обозначить, что функция является методом класса, например, если вы используете `nextcord.ext.commands.Cog` в качестве объекта бота. Но классов я у вас не вижу.

Вы создаете объект `pov = nextcord.Member`, который является ссылкой на класс пользователя, а не конкретным пользователем, а затем пытаетесь выдать роль `await pov.add_roles(role)` объекту класса, вместо того, чтобы выдавать ее экземпляру, который получили как аргумент: `await name.add_roles(role)`

Comment: Я сделал, но тут при использовании возникает ошибка: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_roles'